# How to hide an option of select in drop down menu based on its value - wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have tried to hide an option in a drop down menu created dynamically by a wordpress theme. Here is my code using jquery:

```
jQuery("#role option[value='cars']").hide();  // role is css ID of selection; cars is the value of an <option> of <select>
```

I put that code in a file: /wp-content/themes/my-theme-child/custom-scripts/own-script.js, then I insert the following code into functions.php of wordpress located in my-theme-child/ directory:

```
function add_custom_script() {
    wp_register_script('custom_script', home_url() . '/wp-content/themes/my-theme-child/custom-scripts/own-script.js', array( 'jquery' ));
    wp_enqueue_script('custom_script');
}  
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_custom_script' );
```

Nothing is changed or working.

Can you please give me a right direction?

Comment: can you please tell me the theme name?

Comment: @kani raj, ait theme called businessfinder.

Comment: Does your script load? If you view the page  source, do you find your script? If you enter url.comwp-content/themes/my-theme-child/custom-scripts/own-script.js, do you see your script? If not, the path is incorrect or the file does't exist. Use get_stylesheet_url(). 'custom-scripts/on-script.js'

Comment: @Tom Broucke, yes, I did try that too: wp_register_script('custom_script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 'custom-scripts/own-script.js', array('jquery')); - it is loaded, but nothing is changed or hidden based on my above codes. Any wrong with that?

Comment: Trying putting `alert("Jquery Loaded");` in the script file to see if your script is actually loading on the page.

Comment: @Kyon147, I have tried your suggestion, and when I access this script via a broswer: http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/businessfinder2-child/custom-scripts/own-script.js/ - it opens that file (own-script.js), but it does not displays a text (Jquery Loaded).